# Is there a way to create empty file created at last after output files successfully emitted for each window in Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a streaming pipeline which consumes events tagged with timestamps. All I want to do is to batch them into FixedWindows of 5 mins each and then, write all events in a window into a single / multiple files based on shards, with empty file at last (this file should be created only after all events in that window are successfully emitted into files).

> Basically i would expect an output for like this,
>
> |---window_1_output_file
>
> |---window_1_empty_file (this file should be created only after window_1_output_file has been created).

Window strategy with triggering  being used is as follows,

```
timestampedLines = timestampedLines.apply("FixedWindows", Window.<String>into(
            FixedWindows.of(Utilities.resolveDuration(options.getWindowDuration())))
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(options.getWindowElementCount())))
            .withAllowedLateness(Utilities.resolveDuration(options.getWindowLateness()))
            .accumulatingFiredPanes()
```

Is there a way to create this empty file created at last after output files successfully emitted for each window in Apache Beam? And where to apply this logic to create this additional empty file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you perform sharding? Do you collect the data based on timestamps?

Comment: Yes based on timestamps.

Comment: How do you define number of elements in getWindowElementCount() method? Is it a static or dynamic value? – mk_sta

Comment: What are you using to write to files? FileIO? - I would say that you can add some sort of empty element to your PCollection...

Comment: windows element count is value passed as inputs

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like so:

```java
// Generate one element per window
PCollection<String> empties = p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0)
         .withRate(1, Utilities.resolveDuration(options.getWindowDuration())))
 .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(elm -> "");

// Your actual PCollection data
PCollection<String> myActualData = p.apply...........

PCollection<String> myActualDataWithDataOnEveryWindow = 
              PCollectionTuple.of(empties).and(myActualData).apply(Flatten.create());
```

Once you have an element in every window, you can do what you were doing:

```java
myActualDataWithDataOnEveryWindow.apply("FixedWindows", Window.<String>into(
            FixedWindows.of(Utilities.resolveDuration(options.getWindowDuration())))
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(options.getWindowElementCount())))
            .withAllowedLateness(Utilities.resolveDuration(options.getWindowLateness()))
            .accumulatingFiredPanes())
          .apply(FileIO........);
```

Is this pointing you somewhere useful? Or am I too lost? : )

Comment: Apologies for long delay, as struck with other priorities. This is really useful and given me the new dimension to handle this. Thanks

Comment: If i understand your suggestion right, you meant to say that add an empty element for a window, so as each window while getting emiited to a file system, it creates output files + empty file. Is it? And how is it going to be synchronized as would want the empty file to be created only after window output_file has been created successfullly?

Comment: they get synchronized when you `Flatten` the two PCollections together (see the last line in the first code block). Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Great. when we flatten two PCollections(actual and empty), would this ensure empty file would be created for that window only after actual files are emitted (i.e. flatten would ensure order) as PCollections are processed by individual workers?

Comment: Can we use @onwindowtermination annotation to create empty file ? That ensures being called once per window (end of window)?

Comment: You mean `OnWindowExpiration` right? - https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.22.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.OnWindowExpiration.html